# How to copy my table to a dump table and deletes the values in the main table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

I am working on php codeigniter framework with mysql workbech as back end tool...I have a doubt regarding executing one of the sql query that should be scheduled for one month....like I will explain it in clear...

I have a table named packet data in that table I will get 700K of records per day so totally for 1 month I may get 200K records roughly..and my application runs mainly on this table so because of this, my application runs slow....

So I want to move every month of data to a dump table and should be deleted from the main table so that my application may run fast....

This copying of 1 month data should be done every month and should be deleted form the main table.....

Please can anybody give me the solution how to perform the same delete and copy queries that should be performed in the same query....and whether it is possible or not can you tell me....

Comment: I would not put your email in your question

Comment: It sounds like a better solution would be to redesign the database

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code :-

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col`)  
SELECT col
  FROM table2
 WHERE month(col)=month(curdate() - INTERVAL 1 month)
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

You can create a mysql event which will do this. The link above explain it brifely but MySQL Events are tasks that run according to a schedule. Therefore, we sometimes refer to them as scheduled events. When you create an event, you are creating a named database object containing one or more SQL statements to be executed at one or more regular intervals, beginning and ending at a specific date and time.

there are a few other options like cron events however i would recommend using mysql events because they are made for these types of queries.

There is an example from the website link.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
    EVENT `archive_blogs` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2011-07-24 03:00:00' 
    DO BEGIN

        -- copy deleted posts
        INSERT INTO blog_archive (id, title, content) 
        SELECT id, title, content
        FROM blog
        WHERE deleted = 1;

        -- copy associated audit records
        INSERT INTO audit_archive (id, blog_id, changetype, changetime) 
        SELECT audit.id, audit.blog_id, audit.changetype, audit.changetime 
        FROM audit
        JOIN blog ON audit.blog_id = blog.id
        WHERE blog.deleted = 1;

        -- remove deleted blogs and audit entries
        DELETE FROM blog WHERE deleted = 1;

    END */$$

DELIMITER ;
```

BTW: I do not know too much about your database design, business model or even what type of queries you are running however if you are copying the data over for backup reasons then I would rethink your database design and also think about weather or not you need to store the data in another table or exporting it as a csv file and holding csv files as backup is a more appropriate. Storing Csv files could be a better solution depending on weather or not you need to access that data again through out the months. Think about it however creating a mysql event would do what you wanted to do.

Comment: Yeah thnq dear one solution which u have told i tried the same as importing  my total table data to the csv file the problem is solved the data is deleting in the main table and the data is copying to the csv file....so i want to do the same by scheduling using php like....i mean to say that my code which i have tried is working well but the problem is as i said it should be done monthly and automatically....

Comment: you can export the table to csv with that command create a mysql event which will automatically run evenry month...or you can use cron event